# SQLite Search Like

Tags: sql, sqlite, search, sql-like

I had a problem with search in SQLite.

Example I had a list name in SQLite

```
1. Hello USA
2. Hello Africa
3. Hello Asian
4. I Love Asian
5. I love My Africa
6. Asian
7. Africa
8. Country
9. Hello world
```

When I search name like '%A%'. Result like

```
1. Hello USA
2. Hello Africa
3. Hello Asian
4. I Love Asian
5. I love My Africa
6. Asian
7. Africa
```

But I would like the names starting with the character A be given up the first

```
1. Asian
2. Africa
3. Hello Asian
4. Hello Africa
5. Hello USA
6. I Love Asian
7. I love My Africa
```

Hope you show me the solution this problem. Thank a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the right `order by`:

```
select t.*
from table t
where name like '%A%'
order by (case when name like 'A%' then 0
               when name like '% A%' then 1
               else 2 end),
         name
```

EDIT:

If you want the results order by *where* the letter occurs, then do:

```
order by instr(name, 'A')
```

EDIT II:

If your SQLite doesn't have `instr()`, then you can do the rather painful:

```
order by (case when substr(name, 1, 1) = 'A' then 1
               when substr(name, 2, 1) = 'A' then 2
               when substr(name, 3, 1) = 'A' then 3
               when substr(name, 4, 1) = 'A' then 4
               when substr(name, 5, 1) = 'A' then 5
               when substr(name, 6, 1) = 'A' then 6
               when substr(name, 7, 1) = 'A' then 7
               when substr(name, 8, 1) = 'A' then 8
               when substr(name, 9, 1) = 'A' then 9
               when substr(name, 10, 1) = 'A' then 10
               else 11
           end)
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. But if I would result like Asia, Asian, The Aisa, The Aisan, Hello My Asia, Hello My Aisian..

Comment: sorry Gordon, bother you explain to me locate keywords. I used, It throw "no such function: locate"

Comment: @HuỳnhNgọcBang . . . Apologies.  The right function in SQLite is `instr()` -- assuming you are using a recent version (http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html).

Comment: :) What wrong with me. I can't use this command instr(). SQLite throw error : no such function: instr

Comment: Ok @Gordon, Thank you very much for your enthusiasm.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do two queries - one without the leading `%` and a second with it.  Then concatenate the results in your program.

Comment: This will not work in general.  `union` and `union all` do *not* necessarily preserve the order of the rows in the subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this in your order by clause -

order by(name + " COLLATE NOCASE ASC, ");